Inverse Laplace transform dependent on a parameter
I have to evaluate the inverse Laplace transform of a function of the type $F(s-a)/F(s)$. Clearly, if $a=0$ the solution is the impulse function. If $a$ is not equal to zero, I can compute the residues at the poles of the function ($F(s)=0$). However, it looks as if I do not obtain the impulse function by letting $a \to 0$ in the solution derived from residues. Is the solution for $a$ very close to zero reliable? If yes, how can I justify the discontinuity? Thanks in advance.

you want to isolate the delta function, by computing the inverse Laplace transform of $G(s)=F(s-a)/F(s)-1$ and then adding $\delta(t)$.

Thank you. So simple and so clever!
